# How to force all element to be inline with bootstrap css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have html tags like this and I want to force all elements to be displayed in line.
What is the easiest way to do this with bootstrap? Currently, the page size is on the different line.

thanks

Austin TX

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 form-inline">
    <span class="btn btn-primary">Page Size</span>
    <select class="form-control" style="width:80px">
        <option>20</option>
        <option>30</option>
        <option>40</option>
    </select>

    <ul class="pagination">
        <li><a href="">Previous</a></li>
        <li><a href="">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">3</a></li>
        <li><a href="">4</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Next</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[image: The output]

Answer (score 1):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/5902/)

```
 .algn {

             margin-top: 20px;//This 20px is the margin of .pagination class so to match that else you have to alter pagination class 
             float:left;
    }
```

### Or

```
  .algn {

        display:inline;//and add algn class to ul tag
    }
```

[image: O/p]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if a Bootstrap based solution exists or not, But certainly you can fix it by css.  My Solution will be changing other elements's css little bit. That will apply pagination `margin-top`, `vartical-align` css to other elements .

```
<style>
.algn {
    margin-top: 20px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
</style>


<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 form-inline">
<span class="btn btn-primary algn">Page Size</span>
<select class="form-control algn" style="width:80px;">
    <option>20</option>
    <option>30</option>
    <option>40</option>
</select>

<ul class="pagination">
    <li><a href="">Previous</a></li>
    <li><a href="">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Next</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

UPDATE : I check on bootstrap 3.0.3 version while latest is 3.1.1 .

Comment: jsfiddle.net/52VtD/5901 this is what your code does

Comment: Hmmm I check on bootstrap 3.0.3 version while latest is 3.1.1 . Look like version mismatch done problem.